# My included in every script file - follow-up -3 (the Validator class)

Tags: beginner, php, object-oriented

This question is a sub-post to this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151822/my-included-in-every-script-file-follow-up-1-the-project-has-been-rebuilt-fr)

This post is a follow up for [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147295/my-included-in-every-script-file) and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147351/contact-php-file).

"In this particular question I need the reviewers help to judge my **Validator class**"

---

**Validator.class.php**

a class designed to get used by the controllers. it has one purpose **"handle client inputs"**

```
<?php
namespace aap;

// flags
define('F_REQUIRED', 1);
define('F_MUSTBESET', 2);
define('F_ESCAPE', 4); // if data is valid it can work only with STRING and EMAIL
define('F_SANITIZE', 8); // if data is valid it can work only with STRING and EMAIL

/*
 * define('F_SETIFNOT', 16); // this flag is uselss since passing the $data var
 * by reference will make php define it as null anyway
 * see my question at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483976
 */

// filter types
define('INT', 1);
define('STRING', 2);
define('FLOAT', 3);
define('DATE', 4);
define('EMAIL', 5);
// define('LONGSTRING', 5);

// error types
define('ER_NOT_SET', 10);
define('ER_EMPTY', 11);
define('ER_DATA', 12);

class Validator
{

    protected $options = [];

    protected $errors = [];

    protected $sysModel;

    public function __construct(SystemModel $sysModel, array $options = [])
    {
        $this->sysModel = $sysModel;
        $this->resetOptions();
        $this->setOptions($options);
    }

    public function resetOptions()
    {
        // defaults
        $this->options[INT]['min'] = - 1 * PHP_INT_MAX - 1;
        $this->options[INT]['max'] = PHP_INT_MAX;
        $this->options[STRING]['length'] = 80;
        $this->options[STRING]['regex'] = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ أ-ي]/u";
        $this->options[STRING]['ischarsinvalid'] = true;
        $this->options[FLOAT]['min'] = 0.0;
        $this->options[FLOAT]['max'] = INF;
        $this->options[DATE]['min'] = "1970-01-01"; // mysql timestamp range
        $this->options[DATE]['max'] = "2038-01-18"; // mysql timestamp range
        $this->options[DATE]['format'] = "Y-m-d"; // 2 formats only are supported Y-m-d H:i:s
    }

    /*
     * function validate is designed to report errors in the object $error array
     * @return: the variable $data if it is valid or return false if it is not valid
     * @note: passing by reference will make the
     */
    public function validate(&$data, $varName, $filterType, $flags = null)
    {
        if (! isset($data) && ($flags & F_MUSTBESET)) {
            $this->errors[$varName]['type'] = ER_NOT_SET;
            return false;
        }

        if (empty($data) && ($flags & F_REQUIRED)) {
            $this->errors[$varName]['type'] = ER_EMPTY;
            return false;
        }

        switch ($filterType) {
            case INT:
                if (isset($data) && ($data < $this->options[INT]['min'] || $data > $this->options[INT]['max'])) {
                    $this->errors[$varName]['type'] = ER_DATA;
                    $data = $this->checkEscapeAndSanitize($data, $flags);
                    return false;
                }
                return $data;
                break;
            case STRING:
                // @formatter:off
                if (! empty($data) && (strlen($data) > $this->options[STRING]['length'] || (preg_match($this->options[STRING]['regex'], $data) && $this->options[STRING]['ischarsinvalid']) || (! preg_match($this->options[STRING]['regex'], $data) && ! $this->options[STRING]['ischarsinvalid']))) {
                    // @formatter:on
                    $this->errors[$varName]['type'] = ER_DATA;
                    $data = $this->checkEscapeAndSanitize($data, $flags);
                    return false;
                }
                $data = $this->checkEscapeAndSanitize($data, $flags);
                return $data;
                break;
            case FLOAT:
                if (! empty($data) && ($data < $this->options[FLOAT]['min'] || $data > $this->options[FLOAT]['max'])) {
                    $this->errors[$varName]['type'] = ER_DATA;
                    $data = $this->checkEscapeAndSanitize($data, $flags);
                    return false;
                }
                return $data;
                break;
            case DATE:
                if (! empty($data) && ! Validator::isDate($data, $this->options[DATE]['min'], $this->options[DATE]['max'], $this->options[DATE]['format'])) {
                    $this->errors[$varName]['type'] = ER_DATA;
                    $data = $this->checkEscapeAndSanitize($data, $flags);
                    return false;
                }
                return $data;
                break;
            case EMAIL:
                if (! empty($data) && filter_var($data, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                    $this->errors[$varName]['type'] = ER_DATA;
                    $data = $this->checkEscapeAndSanitize($data, $flags);
                    return false;
                }
                $data = $this->checkEscapeAndSanitize($data, $flags);
                return $data;
                break;
            default:
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'{$filterType}'filterType value is an unknown filter type!");
                break;
        }
    }

    protected function checkEscapeAndSanitize($data, $flags)
    {
        if ($flags & F_ESCAPE) {
            $data = $this->sysModel->escape($data);
        }
        if ($flags & F_SANITIZE) {
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function flushErrors()
    {
        $this->errors = [];
    }

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        foreach ($options as $type => $value) {
            switch ($type) {
                case INT:
                    foreach ($value as $option => $optionValue) {
                        switch ($option) {
                            case "min":
                                if (! filter_var($options[INT]['min'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'{$options[INT]['min']}'[int][min] value is not an integer!");
                                } else {
                                    $this->options[INT]['min'] = $options[INT]['min'];
                                }
                                break;
                            case "max":
                                if (! filter_var($options[INT]['max'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'{$options[INT]['max']}'[int][max] value is not an integer!");
                                } else {
                                    $this->options[INT]['max'] = $options[INT]['max'];
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'$option' is not a valid option name for int data types!");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case STRING:
                    foreach ($value as $option => $optionValue) {
                        switch ($option) {
                            case "length":
                                if (! filter_var($options[STRING]['length'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
                                    "options" => array(
                                        "min_range" => 0
                                    )
                                ))) {
                                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'{$options[STRING]['length']}'[string][length] value is not a positive integer!");
                                } else {
                                    $this->options[STRING]['length'] = $options[STRING]['length'];
                                }
                                break;
                            case "regex":
                                $this->options[STRING]['regex'] = $options[STRING]['regex'];
                                break;
                            case "ischarsinvalid":
                                if (! is_bool($options[STRING]['ischarsinvalid'])) {
                                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'{$options[STRING]['ischarsinvalid']}'[string][ischarsinvalid] value is not a bool!");
                                } else {
                                    $this->options[STRING]['ischarsinvalid'] = $options[STRING]['ischarsinvalid'];
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'$option' is not a valid option name for string data types!");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case FLOAT:
                    foreach ($value as $option => $optionValue) {
                        switch ($option) {
                            case "min":
                                if (! is_numeric($options[FLOAT]['min'])) {
                                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'{$options[FLOAT]['min']}'[float][min] value is not numeric");
                                } else {
                                    $this->options[FLOAT]['min'] = $options[FLOAT]['min'];
                                }
                                break;
                            case "max":
                                if (! is_numeric($options[FLOAT]['max'])) {
                                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'{$options[FLOAT]['max']}'[float][max] value is not numeric!");
                                } else {
                                    $this->options[FLOAT]['max'] = $options[FLOAT]['max'];
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'$option' is not a valid option name for float data types!");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case DATE:
                    foreach ($value as $option => $optionValue) {
                        switch ($option) {
                            case "min":
                                if (! Validator::isDate($options[DATE]['min'])) {
                                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'{$options[DATE]['min']}'[date][min] value is not a date");
                                } else {
                                    $this->options[DATE]['min'] = $options[DATE]['min'];
                                }
                                break;
                            case "max":
                                if (! Validator::isDate($options[DATE]['max'])) {
                                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'{$options[DATE]['max']}'[date][max] value is not a date!");
                                } else {
                                    $this->options[DATE]['max'] = $options[DATE]['max'];
                                }
                                break;
                            case "format":
                                if ($options[DATE]['format'] != "Y-m-d H:i:s" && $options[DATE]['format'] != "Y-m-d") {
                                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'{$options[DATE]['format']}'[date][format] value is not a valid date format");
                                } else {
                                    $this->options[DATE]['format'] = $options[DATE]['format'];
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'$option' is not a valid option name for date data types!");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("'$type' is not a valid type name!");
                    break;
            }
            ;
        }
    }

    public static function compareDatetime($date1, $date2, $unit)
    {
        /*
         * compare 2 dates and return the difference between date1 and date2 \
         * (positive value or nigative)
         * @return date1- date2 or false on failure
         */
        //
        if ($unit != "h" && $unit != "i" && $unit != "s" && $unit != "d") {
            return false;
        }
        ;
        $date1 = strtotime($date1);
        $date2 = strtotime($date2);

        if ($date1 === false || $date2 === false) {
            return false;
        }
        ;
        $diff = $date1 - $date2;
        switch ($unit) {
            case "d":
                return (int) round($diff / (3600 * 24));
            case "h":
                return (int) round($diff / 3600);
            case "i":
                return (int) round($diff / 60);
            case "s":
                return (int) $diff;
        }
    }

    public static function isDate($date, $from = "0001-01-01", $to = "9999-12-31", $format = "Y-m-d")
    {
        // 2 formats only are supported Y-m-d H:i:s Y-m-d
        if ($format != "Y-m-d" && $format != "Y-m-d H:i:s") {
            return false;
        }

        if ($format == "Y-m-d") {
            if (! $from) {
                $from = "0001-01-01";
            }
            ;
            if (! $to) {
                $to = "9999-12-31";
            }
            ;
        } else {
            if (! $from) {
                $from = "0001-01-01 00:00:00";
            }
            ;
            if (! $to) {
                $to = "9999-12-31 00:00:00";
            }
            ;
        }

        if (($date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date)) === false) {
            return false;
        }
        if (\DateTime::getLastErrors()['warning_count'] > 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (($from = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $from)) === false) {
            return false;
        }
        if (\DateTime::getLastErrors()['warning_count'] > 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (($to = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $to)) === false) {
            return false;
        }
        if (\DateTime::getLastErrors()['warning_count'] > 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($date->format("U") < $from->format("U")) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($date->format("U") > $to->format("U")) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**an example of how I plan to use the class**

```
    $validator = new Validator($sysModel);

    //validating inputs
    $options[STRING]['length'] = 20;
    $validator->setOptions($options);
    $validator->validate($_POST['name'], "name", STRING, F_MUSTBESET );
    $options[STRING]['regex'] = "/[^0-9 +]/u";
    $options[STRING]['length'] = 15;
    $validator->setOptions($options);
    $validator->validate($_POST['phone'], "phone", STRING, F_MUSTBESET);
    $validator->resetOptions();
    $options[STRING]['regex'] = "/.*/u";
    $options[STRING]['ischarsinvalid'] = false;
    $options[STRING]['length'] = 500;
    $validator->setOptions($options);
    $validator->validate($_POST['message'], "message", STRING, F_REQUIRED | F_MUSTBESET | F_ESCAPE | F_SANITIZE);
    $validator->validate($_POST['email'], "email", EMAIL, F_MUSTBESET | F_ESCAPE | F_SANITIZE);
    $validator->resetOptions();
    $validator->validate($_POST['title'], "title", STRING, F_MUSTBESET | F_ESCAPE | F_SANITIZE);
    $validator->validate($_POST['subject'], "subject", STRING, F_REQUIRED | F_MUSTBESET | F_ESCAPE | F_SANITIZE);
    $errorMessage = "";
    foreach ($validator->getErrors() as $error => $value) {
        switch ($error) {
            case "name":
                $contact->set("nameInput-class", "incorrect-field");
                $errorMessage .= "<li>name field is not correct!</li>\n";
                // switch ($value['type']) {case ER_NOT_SET:
                break;
            case "phone":
                $contact->set("phoneInput-class", "incorrect-field");
                $errorMessage .= "<li>phone field is not correct!</li>\n";
                break;
            case "email":
                $contact->set("emailInput-class", "incorrect-field");
                $errorMessage .= "<li>email field is not correct!</li>\n";
                break;
            case "subject":
                $contact->set("subjectInput-class", "incorrect-field");
                $errorMessage .= "<li>invalid input!</li>\n";
                break;
            case "title":
                $contact->set("titleInput-class", "incorrect-field");
                $errorMessage .= "<li>title field is not correct!</li>\n";
                break;
            case "message":
                $contact->set("messageInput-class", "incorrect-field");
                $errorMessage .= "<li>message field is not correct!</li>\n";
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you want to achieve, but I guess I would take a different approach.

First you might run into probems with the $options variable in your example usage. If you forget to reset it, older set values will remain and lead to unexpected results.

I would not use such a universial validate() method. I would split it into different methods for text/string, integers, floats, email, ... . That would make calling the validator more intuitive. Because you do not need to remember the correct way to check if the value is a valid email, you just need to call $validator->validateEmail($email);

If you check for a number, I would go for

```
public function validateInteger($value, $min = null, $max = null) { 
    // code to check here 
}
```

See how that make using it a lot easier.

Also you could add some very simple validations like notEmpty(), isSet(), isPositive(), isNumber(), ... . But for all of them php functions exist. So you might reinvent the wheel.

**But make calling your validations as simple as possible.**

The other thing is that in this way it's simple to add another validation method by just inheriting from your class and adding another validateSomethingVeryComplex()-method. Adding validations in your method would require to rewrite your code.

And every validateSomething()-method should return true or false, depending on the result of the validation. An additional error could be included in a by reference param. But you will run into situations, where you do not want all errors at the end, but need a result right when you validate.

And sanitizing/escaping is not part of validation, but a seperate thing to do. I would not mix these two topics.

Comment: Yes that is what happened with me, I forgot to `resetOptions()` yesterday and it takes about an hour till I figured out  the cause of the unexpected results. I will separate the validate function as you said . I think that will also save some switch logic in the global validate function.. and as for sanitizing and escaping the input,  I liked the idea of  having 1 class to do all the logic related to the client inputs (sanitizing, escaping, validating) . thank you for your time